# Eclipse will not run C programs

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, cygwin

I just recently installed the CDT plugin for Eclipse in Windows 8 and I'm getting the error:

> "Launch failed.  Binary not found."

Now I've looked into this and I have installed cygwin with gcc and set that up in Eclipse settings.  I went to `Window>Preferences>New C/C++ Project Wizard>Makefile` Project and checked Cygwin PE Parser (and just in case I checked PE Windows Parser as well).

Then I went to `Window>Preferences>Build>Environment` and added my PATH variable there.  I made sure to add `C:\cygwin64\bin` to my PATH in my system settings, and I know this is valid because I checked that location and I have successfully run `gcc` through the command line as well as the `cygwin` terminal.  On top of this, if I build my project in Eclipse and then navigate to that directory outside of Eclipse and run the `.exe` that it creates by double-clicking on it, it also runs properly.

I'm at a loss for why Eclipse can't run it but everything else can...Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click your project in eclipse "project explore" -> Run as -> Run configuration
=>select your project name then check "Main" tab, in C/C++ application file. is it point to your binary file?
E.g:
   Debug/TestProj.exe