# can't launch C program using eclipse IDE

Tags: c, eclipse, ide, mingw

when i run a program in eclipse IDE with compiler minGW getting this error Error starting process. Cannot run program "C:\Users\My book\eclipse-workspace\test\src\test.c":
[image]

Comment: It looks as if you're trying to launch the `.c` file instead of the `.exe`...

Comment: Though it always surprises me to see that problem described, don't we have a few duplicates for "cannot run the .c script"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse will not run C programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627468/eclipse-will-not-run-c-programs)